# OSX sound output split across two USB devices

Tags: audio, usb, headset

If two headsets are both connected to USB ports in OS X, the Preferences => Sound => Output pane only allows the user to select one of them at a time.

I thought at first that there might be a way to "split" the output so that both USB devices receive it, as one can do with minijack-headsets connected to the audio output jack using a splitter. But I find that using a USB hub does not change how the operating system treats the two devices as distinct.

However, is there a way to direct the same output to two or more devices simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that doesn't involve special scripting. OS X has a utility called Audio MIDI Setup that allows creation of a "multi-output device" that will send the same output to multiple output devices.